# Saving to a file using multiple JBUTTONS in JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface, file-io, try-catch, jbutton

I am having trouble SAVING to a File and READING from a File. I have 6 TextFields and 5 JButtons. I have a save button in 2 of the panels. I would like to understand how to save to another file using JBUTTONS.

Any Examples with comments would be nice. I am mostly a visual learner. I want it to save out the file for the Customers name, Employee ID, wood type, carpet color, area, and total.
THANK YOU

Here is my Code

```
package courseProject;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FlooringStore {

//global
JPanel P, P1, P2, P3;
JButton B, B1, B2, B3, B4;
JLabel JL;
JTabbedPane TP;
JTextField JT = new JTextField(50);

String woodType, carpetType;
double woodArea, carpetArea;
double wArea, cArea, totalWood, totalCarpet;


public FlooringStore(){

    JTabbedPane TP = new JTabbedPane();
    JFrame JF = new JFrame();
    JF.setVisible(true); //made true so we can see the frame
    JF.setTitle("FLOORING STORE");
    JF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JF.setSize(400,300); //set size Width/Height
    JF.add(TP); //ands the TabbedPanel to frame

    P = new JPanel();
    P.setLayout(null);
    JL = new JLabel("WELCOME TO THE FLOORING STORE");
    JL.setSize(300,100);
    JL.setLocation(85,50);
    P.add(JL);
    TP.add(P, "HOME PAGE"); //panel1 tab1 name

    P1 = new JPanel();
    P1.setLayout(null);
    B = new JButton("CUSTOMER");
    B.setSize(150,150);
    B.setLocation(20,20);
    B1 = new JButton("EMPLOYEE");
    B1.setSize(150,150);
    B1.setLocation(200,20);
    P1.add(B);
    P1.add(B1);
    TP.add(P1, "ID"); //panel 2 tab2 

    class customerB implements ActionListener{ 
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            JFrame JF2 = new JFrame();
            JF2.setVisible(true);
            JF2.setTitle("CUSTOMER");
            JF2.setSize(400,300);


            JPanel JP = new JPanel();
            JP.setLayout(null);
            JF2.add(JP);

            JLabel L2 = new JLabel("CUSTOMER NAME: ");
            L2.setSize(300,100);
            L2.setLocation(10,20);
            JP.add(L2);

            JTextField JT = new JTextField(50);
            JT.setSize(200,20);
            JT.setLocation(120, 60);
            JP.add(JT);

            JButton B5 = new JButton("ENTER");
            B5.setSize(100,50);
            B5.setLocation(100,100);
            JP.add(B5);

    class okB implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            try{
                JTextField JT = new JTextField(50);
                JT.setSize(200,20);
                JT.setLocation(120, 60);
                JP.add(JT);

                String name = JT.getText();
                FileWriter stream = new FileWriter("customer.txt", true);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(stream);
                out.write(name);
                out.close();
                }/*end try*/ catch (Exception ex){  
                    System.out.println("ERROR!! %s");
            }//end catch
        }//end actionPerformed
    }//end end action z

    B5.addActionListener(new okB());

        }// end actionPerformed
    }//end end action 
    B.addActionListener(new customerB());

    class employeeB implements ActionListener{ 
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            JFrame JF3 = new JFrame();
            JF3.setVisible(true);
            JF3.setTitle("EMPLOYEE");
            JF3.setSize(400,300);

            JPanel JP = new JPanel();
            JP.setLayout(null);
            JF3.add(JP);

            JLabel L2 = new JLabel("EMPLOYEE NAME: ");
            L2.setSize(300,100);
            L2.setLocation(10,20);
            JP.add(L2);

            JTextField JT1 = new JTextField(50); //EmployeeName
            JT1.setSize(200,20);
            JT1.setLocation(120, 60);
            JP.add(JT1);

            JLabel L3 = new JLabel("EMPLOYEE ID: ");
            L3.setSize(300,100);
            L3.setLocation(10,60);
            JP.add(L3);

            JTextField JT2 = new JTextField(30); //EmployeeID
            JT2.setSize(100,20);
            JT2.setLocation(100, 100);
            JP.add(JT2);
        }// end actionPerformed
    }//end end action 
    B1.addActionListener(new employeeB());


    P2 = new JPanel();
    P2.setLayout(null);
    B2 = new JButton("WOOD");
    B2.setSize(150,150);
    B2.setLocation(20,20);
    B3 = new JButton("CARPET");
    B3.setSize(150,150);
    B3.setLocation(200,20);
    P2.add(B2);
    P2.add(B3);
    TP.add(P2, "FLOORING"); //panel 3 tab3 

    class woodB implements ActionListener{ 
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

            JFrame JF4 = new JFrame();
            JF4.setVisible(true);
            JF4.setTitle("WOOD");
            JF4.setSize(400,300);

            JPanel JP = new JPanel();
            JP.setLayout(null);
            JF4.add(JP);

            JLabel L4 = new JLabel("TYPE OF WOOD: ");
            L4.setSize(300,100);
            L4.setLocation(10,20);
            JP.add(L4);

            JTextField JT3 = new JTextField(50); //wood Type
            JT3.setSize(250,20);
            JT3.setLocation(120, 60);
            JP.add(JT3);

            JLabel L5 = new JLabel("AREA OF THE ROOM: ");
            L5.setSize(300,100);
            L5.setLocation(10,80);
            JP.add(L5);

            JTextField JT4 = new JTextField(50); //Area
            JT4.setSize(100,20);
            JT4.setLocation(130, 120);
            JP.add(JT4);


        }// end actionPerformed
    }//end end action 
    B2.addActionListener(new woodB());

    class carpetB implements ActionListener{ 
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            JFrame JF4 = new JFrame();
            JF4.setVisible(true);
            JF4.setTitle("CARPET");
            JF4.setSize(400,300);

            JPanel JP = new JPanel();
            JP.setLayout(null);
            JF4.add(JP);

            JLabel L5 = new JLabel("COLOR OF CARPET: ");
            L5.setSize(300,100);
            L5.setLocation(10,20);
            JP.add(L5);

            JTextField JT4 = new JTextField(50); //carpet color
            JT4.setSize(250,20);
            JT4.setLocation(130, 60);
            JP.add(JT4);

            JLabel L6 = new JLabel("AREA OF THE ROOM: ");
            L6.setSize(300,100);
            L6.setLocation(10,80);
            JP.add(L6);

            JTextField JT5 = new JTextField(50); //Area
            JT5.setSize(100,20);
            JT5.setLocation(130, 120);
            JP.add(JT5);
        }// end actionPerformed
    }//end end action 
    B3.addActionListener(new carpetB());

    P3 = new JPanel();
    P3.setLayout(null);
    B4 = new JButton("TOTAL");
    B4.setSize(150,150);
    B4.setLocation(100,20);
    P3.add(B4);
    TP.add(P3, "CHECKOUT"); //panel 3 tab4

    class totalB implements ActionListener{ 
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total Amount for "+JT+ "\nWood Type: "+woodType+"\n Carpet Type: "
            +carpetType+"\n\n Total Amount: "+totalWood+" "+totalCarpet);

        }// end actionPerformed
    }//end end action 
    B4.addActionListener(new totalB());

    }//end constructor


public static void main(String[] args) {

    new FlooringStore();
}
```

}

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total Amount for "+JT+...` this call to `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` is where your problem is, as the string you're passing to this method is resulting in an implicit call to the `toString` method of the `JT` object, which is your `JTextField`. I assume you want `JT.getText()` and not just `JT` there.

Comment: I just fixed that code and nothing shows up in the message box and the customer.txt

Can you show me an example on how to get the users input to save into the file?

Comment: Well, nothing shows up because you never assign anything to the variables you're printing. `totalWood` for example, is never set. I'm not sure where it's supposed to be set, but you need to assign a value to it, maybe in one of your other ActionListeners, and it should show up in the message box.